# Python: parsing structured text to CSV format

Tags: python, csv, text

I want to convert plain structured text files to the CSV format using Python.

The input looks like this

```
[-------- 1 -------]
Version: 2
 Stream: 5
 Account: A
[...]
[------- 2 --------]
 Version: 3
 Stream: 6
 Account: B
[...]
```

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
Version; Stream; Account; [...]
2; 5; A; [...]
3; 6; B; [...]
```

I.e. the input is structured text records delimited by `[----<sequence number>----]` and containing `<key>: <values>`-pairs and the ouput should be CSV containing one record per line.

I am able to retrive the `<key>: <values>`-pairs into CSV format via

```
colonseperated = re.compile(' *(.+) *: *(.+) *')
fixedfields = re.compile('(\d{3} \w{7}) +(.*)')
```

-- but I have trouble to recognize beginning and end of the structured text records and with the re-writing as CSV line-records. Furthermore I would like to be able to separate different type of records, i.e. distinguish between - say - `Version: 2` and `Version: 3` type of records.

Comment: Your input file is *not* a CSV format; it is structured, but not delimiter-separated. Your output *is*.

Comment: And what do you expect to do with the different versions of records?

Comment: The different type of records have a different number of elements.

Comment: ah, that makes a difference; your output then is not strictly CSV either. My answer below assumed the records *were* the same size each.

Comment: Do you know what fields are used beforehand? Or do you need to collect those first from the input file?

Comment: Yes, name and number of fields are known, just the occurence of the different record types within the file is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the list is not that hard:

```
def read_records(iterable):
    record = {}
    for line in iterable:
        if line.startswith('[------'):
            # new record, yield previous
            if record:
                yield record
            record = {}
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
        record[key.strip()] = value.strip()

    # file done, yield last record
    if record:
        yield record
```

This produces dictionaries from your input file.

From this you can produce CSV output using the `csv` module, specifically the [`csv.DictWriter()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
# List *all* possible keys, in the order the output file should list them
headers = ('Version', 'Stream', 'Account', ...)

with open(inputfile) as infile, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    records = read_records(infile)

    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, headers, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()

    # and write
    writer.writerows(records)
```

Any header keys missing from a record will leave that column empty for that record. Any *extra* headers you missed will raise an exception; either add those to the `headers` tuple, or set the `extrasaction` keyword to the `DictWriter()` constructor to `'ignore'`.

Comment: thanks for the valuable&well explained hints. I do have a working prototype now. There's one problem, still. With the full number of headers (approx. 100) there is no proper output generated just one line of wrongly mapped fields: Is there a limitation to `csv(headers)`?

Comment: Not that I know of; sounds like something else might be wrong instead.